# Como dar zoom na imagem quando o mouse passa em cima?

Tags: html, css

Tipo o desse site -> https://flamengomaior.com.br/

Um zoom suave feito o desse site. Qual a maneira mais simples de se fazer isso? Se possivel em CSS/HTMl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você usa `scale` na imagem com `:hover` e `overflow: hidden` na `div` que a contém. Você ajusta o `scale` conforme seu gosto onde, `1.1`, por exemplo, aumenta a imagem em 10%, e `.5s` é o tempo da transição (meio segundo ou 500 milissegundos).

A função `scale` basicamente altera o *zoom* do elemento (**[mais sobre aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)**).

O `overflow: hidden` evita que a imagem *vaze* para fora da `div` ao aplicar o zoom.

A estrutura básica seria esta usando uma `div`, mas você pode usar um link `<a>` também, se desejar:

```css
.img-container{
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 2px solid #000;
}

.img-container img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s ease;
   transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.img-container:hover img{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado colega! Ficou perfeito.

Comment: Se eu aplicar essa técnica no meu dinheiro ele vai crescer?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo só enquanto o pointer do mouse estiver em cima dele

Comment: @bacco, nesse caso na hora de pagar as contas faço isso com transform: scale(1.9);. :)